# Form Authentication w/ multiple login pages

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have read the many posts of people trying to use two different login pages: one for users and one for admins.  My question is very different.  I have a Site.master page with a LoginView and LoginControl.  I then have three root level pages Default.aspx, About.aspx, and Contact.aspx that derive from the Site.master.  All three pages are set in the web.config to be allowed to all users.  I then have a MemberPage in a Member folder which is only accessible to authenticated users.  What I want to have happen is to be able to login from either the Default, About, or Contact pages and then be directed to the MemberPage.

The way Form Authentication is set now, I can only have one loginUrl and one defaultUrl.  Which means if I have this settings in my web.config:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="ishAuth" loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="50" defaultUrl="~/Member/MemberPage.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>`

the only page that redirects to the /Member/MemberPage.aspx is the Default.aspx.  I want my users to be able to browse through the anonymous section of the site and login from any page and then be redirected to the MemberPage.  Right now if I am on the About.aspx page and log in I am authenticated but remain on the About page.

Is there a way around the properties of the  element?  Can I turn off the default actions of the  element and do the redirect using my own custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Visual studio right now, but you should be able to use the "OnLoggedIn" event of the login control to do what you want. Create the even handler for that event, and simply just put `Response.Redirect("~/Member/MemberPage.aspx")` and your users should get redirected to the right page.

You can have a look at [this page on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I totally forgot I read about the Login Control Methods.  However, I tried this: Response.Redirect("~/Member/MemberPage.aspx") and FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("~/Member/MemberPage.aspx", rememberMe.Checked) and neither of them worked.

Comment: Actually I take that back.  It did work.  In my haste for a cure I forgot to go to the Site.master aspx page and place the OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn" property in the LoginControl.  I works awesomely now.  much thanks